# Divergent $3n+1$ sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, open-problem, collatz-conjecture

Recall the Collatz function given by:
$$
T(n) = \begin{cases}
{\dfrac{n}{2}} & n \equiv 0\pmod 2\\
& \\
3n+1 & n \equiv 1\pmod 2
\end{cases}
$$
The well-known conjecture states that $T^{(k)}(n)=1$ for all $n$, and $k$ large enough.

Is it correct that this is not known that $T^{(k)}(n)\to\infty$ does not occur for any $n$, as $k\to\infty$. What is known about this aspect of the problem?

Comment: I think that it is not known is there some number starting from which the sequence will show the tendency to possibly diverge to infinity, but someone will know more than I.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture#Cycles

Comment: Yes, this is still unproven for most numbers (those greater than about $10^{60}$).  It may in fact not even be provable since even if we found some such trajectory, the fact that it would be infinitely long means we could never follow it for long enough to show it has no end. Although few skilled mathematicians think this will be the case.

Comment: @RobertFrost: upps, the recently marked high number is $5 \times 2^{60}$ or so but not $10^{60}$

Comment: @GottfriedHelms I deliberately worded so my statement would be true without having to look up the exact number ;)

Comment: @Robert : well :-) so this shall be true for the upcoming historical aeras... How could I have missed that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I should have looked harder: a [2010 survey](https://www.huerta-network.com/es/pdf/mathematics/syracuse/mbk-78-prev.pdf) of Jeff Lagarias on p.22 conjecture (C2) exactly answers this (as of 2010, of course):

> Does the 3x + 1 function have a divergent trajectory, i.e., an integer
>   starting value whose iterates are un- bounded? This is conjectured not
>   to be the case.